# Getting empty dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this code:

```
 def saveInfo(self):
    
            info = {}
            info["title"] : self.getHeading()
            info["user"] : self.getUser()
            info["location"] : self.file_path
            info["uploaded"] : False
    
            print(info)
            self.writeToJSONFile(self.workspace, 'ri', info)
```

but whenever i print the 'info' or try to save in json, I only get this printed: `{}`
and json file be like: `{}{}{}{}...`

Comment: use `=` not `:` when assigning , [refer here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing dictionary assignment and literal syntax (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)) and accidentally not causing syntax errors because it looks like a [type annotation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/).

The idiomatic way to construct this dictionary would be:

```
info = {
    "title": self.getHeading(),
    "user": self.getUser(),
    "location": self.file_path,
    "uploaded": False,
}
```

Alternatively, you can assign each key one at a time with the `=` operator (*not* `:`!):

```
info = {}
info["title"] = self.getHeading()
info["user"] = self.getUser()
info["location"] = self.file_path
info["uploaded"] = False
```